# Set a maximum number of selected items

Tags: listview, gridview, windows-runtime, max, selecteditem

This might be a silly question, but... How could I implement a maximum number of selected items within a listview/gridview?

I'm having a listview with 9 items, from which I'd like the user to be able to select only 5.

So far, I'm having this implemented in the `SelectionChanged` event :

```
if (MyListView.SelectedItems.Count >5)
    MyListView.SelectedItems.RemoveAt(0);
```

Which is a funny but evasive way to make it, when the 6th item gets selected, the 1st gets deselcted, so alwyays they remain 5.

What I'd like though, when I have 5 items already selected, to be unable to select others any further, unless I deselect an item meanwhile and I meet the condition of `SelectedItems.Count` < 5.

Any suggestions, ideas, code is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

It was a silly question indeed... Been thinking a lot and I had no ideas at all, only 5 minutes after I posted this... and the code looks like this :

```
if (MyListView.SelectedItems.Count >5)
    MyListView.SelectedItems.RemoveAt(MyListView.SelectedItems.Count-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

EventHandler:

```
    this.MyListView.ItemSelectionChanged += new  System.Windows.Forms.ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventHandler(this.MyListView_ItemSelectionChanged);
```

Code:

```
    private void MyListView_ItemSelectionChanged(object sender,     ListViewItemSelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (MyListView.SelectedItems.Count > 5)
        { MyListView.SelectedItems[0].Selected = false; }
    }
```

Comment: My example removes the first item that was selected, your solution removes the last item selected before the new one. Whatever works for you.